# Strange behavior of NSTextField with NSAttributedString with attachments

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsattributedstring

When I place image attachment in NSTextField via NSAttributedString, when I click it or change it, images disappears. What's wrong?

```
NSTextAttachment* attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
NSImage *symbolImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"enabled.png"];
NSLog(@"%@", symbolImage);
NSTextAttachmentCell *anAttachmentCell = [[NSTextAttachmentCell
                                           alloc] initImageCell:symbolImage];
[attachment setAttachmentCell:anAttachmentCell];
return [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment];
```

Comment: can you show in code how you are doing your image attachment via NSAttributedString?

Comment: Did you resolve this? I've got the same issue with links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684972/nstextfields-attributed-string-is-delayed-in-rendering

Comment: not, I didn't :( please tell me if you will

Comment: Any insight on this? I am stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Actually, the fix is quite straight forward. Just enable "Rich Text" to the field where you need to display image.

Once text attachment is inserted, image remains there even after changing focus to another view.

Answer (score 3):

The above answer by billibala can also be implemented in code.
For the `NSTextField` set

```
allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
```